# How to Fix No Buffer Space Available When Running Java API (Jetty + Java Service Wrapper)?

Tags: java, jetty, ubuntu-16.04, jetty-8, java-service-wrapper

I developed simple JAVA API and using Jetty as the servlet also Java Service Wrapper as the framework.

I found this error, when I restarted the wrapper several times because of frequently updating the .jar file:

```
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available
```

I never found this issue when I deployed it on my office dedicated server.
But, I got this issue from VPS which I rented with these specs:

```
root@dev:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
root@dev:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz"
cpu MHz     : 1679.601
cpu MHz     : 1679.601
cpu MHz     : 1679.601
cpu MHz     : 1679.601
root@dev:~# lshw -c cpu
  *-cpu                   
       product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: cpu@0
       width: 64 bits
       capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr 
pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall
nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology
nonstop_tsc aperfmperf cpuid_faulting pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx
smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt
tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb pln pts
dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt
root@dev:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2048         342        1591         154         114        1592
Swap:          4096           1        4094
root@dev:~# netstat -atunp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      399/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      266/rpcbind     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      436/nginx -g daemon
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      372/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      589/master      
tcp        0      0 10.10.28.56:22          202.62.19.84:13660      ESTABLISHED 2435/sshd: rendy [p
tcp        0     52 10.10.28.56:22          202.62.19.84:16553      ESTABLISHED 2958/1          
tcp        0      0 10.10.28.56:22          202.62.19.84:14998      ESTABLISHED 2671/sshd: rendy [p
tcp        0      0 10.10.28.56:22          202.62.19.84:6601       ESTABLISHED 597/sshd: rendy [pr
tcp        0      0 10.10.28.56:22          202.62.19.84:16287      ESTABLISHED 2918/sshd: rendy [p
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      266/rpcbind     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      436/nginx -g daemon
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      372/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      589/master      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:866             0.0.0.0:*                           266/rpcbind     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           266/rpcbind     
udp6       0      0 :::866                  :::*                                266/rpcbind     
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                266/rpcbind
```

Any idea what is causing this to happen?

---

**NOTE**
After I restarted the VPS, the problem is solved. But, I don't know when it will happen again. Maybe after 15times of keep restarting the wrapper.

Comment: What does your `netstat` tell you when this issue hits?

Comment: okay. edited in the question

Comment: do you have really low `ulimits` set perhaps?

Comment: what is ulimit? can you explain thoroughly?